# no puedo implementar clase svm multiLabel en JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

encontre este codigo

```
    var trainSet = [
{ input:'What is your name',output: "name" },
{ input:'how are you',output: "fine"},
{ input:'please tell your name please',output: "name" },
{ input:'your name please',output: "name" },
{ input:'what is your name',output: "name" },
{ input:'who am i',output: "listener" },
{ input:'who are you ',output: "name" },
{ input:'may i know your name',output: "name" },
{ input:'your name',output: "name" },
{ input:'where you coming from',output: "about" },
{ input:'how do you do',output: "fine" },
{ input:'how are you doing',output: "fine"},
{ input:'how are you',output: "fine"},
{ input:'how do you do',output: "fine"},
{ input:'how are you',output: "fine"},
{ input:'what do you do',output: "fine"},
{ input:'can you edit this',output: "edit"},


]

actionClassifier.trainBatch(trainSet);



console.log(actionClassifier.classify('who are you'))
console.log(actionClassifier.classify('how are you'))
```

en https://www.npmjs.com/package/multilabelsvm 
mi duda es que esta lib creo que solo admite array y no archivos para el entrenamiento